# Play framework: scala template, if statement issue

Tags: java, scala, if-statement, playframework

I can't figure out why this doesn't work, here is my template code:

```
@workuserForm: Form[WorkUser],queues: List[Queue])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("User Form"){

@helper.form(action = routes.Users.saveWorkUser() , 'class -> "form-horizontal"){

@for(queue <- queues){
    @repeat(workuserForm("queues"), min = 0){ wuQueue =>
        @wuQueue("id").value  
        @queue.id
        @if(wuQueue("id").value == queue.id){
           checked
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get:

---

1 1

1 2

1 3

2 1

2 2

2 3

3 1

3 2

3 3

---

Where I should get:

---

1 1 checked

1 2

1 3

2 1

2 2 checked

2 3

3 1

3 2

3 3 checked

---

My models:

```
public class WorkUser
{
    public String showName;
    public List<Queue> queues = new ArrayList<Queue>();
}


public class Queue extends Model
{
    public long id;
    public String name;
}
```

My controller ( where I call the scala template)

```
public class Users extends Controller
{
    private static final Form<WorkUser> workuserForm = Form.form(WorkUser.class);
    public static Result newWorkUser()
    {
        List<Queue> queues = Queue.findAll();
        WorkUser workUserAux = new WorkUser();
        workUserAux.queues = queues;
        Form<WorkUser> filledForm = workuserForm.fill(workUserAux);
        return ok(views.html.workUser.render(filledForm,queues));
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem is in the if statement but i can't solve it , I've tried all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wuQueue("id").value` is of type `String` and `queue.id` is of type `Long`, so your equality check will never pass. Consider rewriting it as:

```
@if(wuQueue("id").value.toLong == queue.id){
  checked
}
```

Comment: When I tried casting to long I got this error

"value toLong is not a member of Option[String]"

I've also tried to convert to string but nothing:


@if(wuQueue("id").value == queue.id.toString){
  checked
}

Comment: How about @if(wuQueue("id").value.get.toLong == queue.id)? `value` is an Option of String, not a String.